# How do I score values ​in a row by size?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-analysis

I have data like this:

```py
|   | name      | time | electoral_not | government_not | political_participation_not | cultur_not | civil_not |
|---|-----------|------|---------------|----------------|-----------------------------|------------|-----------|
| 0 | Iceland   | 2018 | 163           | 162            | 165                         | 166        | 161       |
| 1 | Norway    | 2018 | 160           | 165            | 166                         | 164        | 159       |
| 2 | Australia | 2018 | 166           | 158            | 153                         | 160        | 166       |
```

I want to score this data from 1 to 5 for each row:

```py
|   | name      | time | electoral_not | government_not | political_participation_not | cultur_not | civil_not |
|---|-----------|------|---------------|----------------|-----------------------------|------------|-----------|
| 0 | Iceland   | 2018 | 3             | 2              | 4                           | 5          | 1         |
| 1 | Norway    | 2018 | 2             | 4              | 5                           | 3          | 1         |
| 2 | Australia | 2018 | 4.5           | 2              | 1                           | 3          | 4.5       |
```

If there is more than one same value in a row, they should be averaged.
**Example for Australia** 
Values:
`166  158 153 160 166` 
Sorted:
`153 158 160 166 166` 
Scrore_table:
`1 2 3 4 5` 
Result:

```py
| 4       | 2 | 1 | 3 | 5       |
|---------|---|---|---|---------|
| (4+5)/2 | 2 | 1 | 3 | (5+4)/2 |
| 4.5     | 2 | 1 | 3 | 4.5     |
```

I was only do that:

```py
def fun(x):
    row = list(x[2:7])
    x[2:7] = find_note(row)
    return x

def find_note(row):
    ranked = row.copy()
    ranked.sort()
    row = deque(row)
    note=[]
    while row:
        value = row.popleft()
        for i in range(5):
            if value==ranked[i]:
                note.append(i+1)
                break
    return note

x = combined.apply(lambda x: fun(x), axis=1)[['name','time','electoral_not','government_not','political_participation_not','cultur_not','civil_not']]
```

and result:

```
| name | time      | electoral_not | government_not | political_participation_not | cultur_not | civil_not |   |
|------|-----------|---------------|----------------|-----------------------------|------------|-----------|---|
| 0    | Iceland   | 2018          | 3              | 2                           | 4          | 5         | 1 |
| 1    | Norway    | 2018          | 2              | 4                           | 5          | 3         | 1 |
| 2    | Australia | 2018          | 4              | 2                           | 1          | 3         | 4 |
| 3    | Denmark   | 2018          | 5              | 4                           | 2          | 3         | 1 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [rank](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) method has an average argument.

```
df[['electoral_not','government_not','political_participation_not','cultur_not','civil_not']].rank(method='average', axis=1)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! Thank u.